# Integrating twitter with Ruby on Rails to display dynamic feeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a Ruby on Rails application and **integrated twitter**. But i am facing some issues while running it. I have an index page with a **search box** and a **submit button**. The application tries to search the keywords entered on twitter and then display it dynamically on the application page(the create.html.page for dynamically displaying tweets). So there is a "tweet controller" and two html.erb files. "Index.html.erb" , "create.html.erb" . And a model. The index method in controller is used to display feeds using a **specific keyword** (You can say like a **static** way). The create method is used to **dynamically display the tweets** based on the keyword entered in the index.html.erb. I wanted to avoid using form_for or form_tag so created a form using html form tag.

When i try to execute the url "http:localhost:3000/tweets/create" it displays an error that **symbol as array index**
When i try to execute the url "http:localhost:3000/tweets/index" , the page is not rendered. Kindly help. I m posting the controller, views below.

Thanks,
bhargav

**"Index.html.erb"**

```
<h1>Tweets about New Year Resolution</h1>


<form action="/create" method="post">
<label for="keyword">keyword</label>
  <input id="keyword" name="Enter keyword" size="30" type="text" />

<input type="submit" value="search" />

</form>

 <% if (@tweets != nil) then %>
   print "The tweets are " @tweets
  <% else %>
   print "No tweets for the keyword"
 <% end % >


<div id="container">
<ul>
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <li class="<%=cycle('odd', '')%>">
        <%= link_to tweet.from_user, "http://twitter.com/#{tweet.from_user}", :class => "username", :target => "_blank" %>  
        <div class="tweet_text_area">
            <div class="tweet_text">
                <%=raw display_content_with_links(tweet.text) %>
            </div>
            <div class="tweet_created_at">
                <%= time_ago_in_words tweet.twitter_created_at %> ago
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>`enter code here`
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
```

**"create.html.erb"**

```
<h1>Keywords displayed</h1>
<p> A page to display tweets
</p>
```

**"tweets_controller.rb"**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #Get the tweets (records) from the model Ordered by 'twitter_created_at' descending

    if Tweet.count > 0                         
      Tweet.delete_all        
    end    
    Tweet.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets("India")

    @tweets = Tweet.order("twitter_created_at desc")   
  end

  def create
    @tweets = (params [:tweet][:search])
    Tweet.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets(@tweets)
  end
end
```

The **model** **tweet.rb** contains the method get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets . It is as below.

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base

  #A method to grab latest tweets from Twitter
  def self.get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets(keyword)

    #create a Twitter Search object
    search = Twitter::Search.new

    #grab recent 100 tweets which contain 'new year resolution' words, and loop each of them
    search.containing(keyword).result_type("recent").per_page(100).fetch.each do |tweet_results|

      #parsing the string 'created_at' to DateTime object
      twitter_created_at = DateTime.parse(tweet_results.created_at)

      #making sure we are not saving exact same tweet from a person again 
      unless Tweet.exists?(['twitter_created_at = ? AND from_user_id_str = ?', DateTime.parse(tweet_results.created_at), tweet_results.from_user_id_str])

        #finally creating the tweet record
        Tweet.create!({
            :from_user => tweet_results.from_user,
            :from_user_id_str => tweet_results.from_user_id_str,
            :profile_image_url => tweet_results.profile_image_url,
            :text => tweet_results.text,
            :twitter_created_at => twitter_created_at
        })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: looks like the method `get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets` expects an array but is getting a hash, as the index in a hash is a symbol it throws the error, need to see the method def to be precise though.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the model containing the "get_latest_new_year_resolution_tweets" method.